# how to show specified country state in android

Tags: android, android-mapview

i want to show particular country map and indicate only its state with region.

```
MapView maps=(MapView) findViewById(R.id.mapView);
maps.setSatellite(true);
final MapController mapControl = maps.getController();
mapControl.setZoom(17);
GeoPoint newPoint = new
GeoPoint((int)(42 * 1E6), (int)(2 * 1E6));
mapControl.animateTo(newPoint);
```

i use this code but it show me the france map but it doesnot indicate state with specified region in one fixed screen. so please help me and helpers must appreciated..

Comment: you should put more effort into properly indenting your code... this is kind of ridiculous.

Answer (score 1):

You have to give particular latitude and longitude for country or state and assign Geopoint  for example

Latitude and longitude for india is 21.7679° N, 78.8718° E

if you pass these value then map will show particular country..

Comment: i have already given the latitude and longitude even i use the method animate to but by doing this, it show geographical part and i only want the state name of that country..